# Dynamically formatting file names for exporting using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm very new to GEE and JavaScript and I am trying to export multiple landsat 8 satellite images for the same region over time. For example, let's say I want to extract images of the Seattle area from 2020 to 2021, I'd like to extract the overlayed areas for a specific bounding box (called `Seattle` below). For one image, let's say the latest image in the dataset, the following code works perfectly fine:

```
var Seattle = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Point([-122.33862779953088, 47.61587948975889]),
    roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-122.59977751620073, 48.080847739249094],
          [-122.59977751620073, 47.34535322143622],
          [-121.85270720370073, 47.34535322143622],
          [-121.85270720370073, 48.080847739249094]]], null, false);
          


var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .aside(print)
  .filterBounds(roi).aside(print, 'In roi')
  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31').aside(print, 'In 2013')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .first();
  
var visParams = {bands:["B4","B3","B2"], min: 0, max: 0.3, gamma: 1.4};

// These are for the Code Editor - it will show the photo to be exported
Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), visParams, "Output");
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);

var imageRGB = image.visualize({bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.3, gamma:1.4});
print("rgb",imageRGB);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imageRGB,
  description: "Seattle2013",
  folder: "sidv2",
  scale: 10,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  shardSize: 1024
  });
```

Since there are more than one images, I would like to dynamically format the file name and export the result to Google Drive. To be clear, I am expecting the file names to be somewhere along the lines of:

```
Seattle_2020-09-08
Seattle_2020-04-08
Seattle_2020-03-16
```

So I tried to write a function to map over the `ImageCollection` class:

```
var Seattle = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Point([-122.33862779953088, 47.61587948975889]),
    roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-122.59977751620073, 48.080847739249094],
          [-122.59977751620073, 47.34535322143622],
          [-121.85270720370073, 47.34535322143622],
          [-121.85270720370073, 48.080847739249094]]], null, false);
          
function exportImageRGB(image){
  var visParams = {bands:["B4","B3","B2"], min: 0, max: 0.3, gamma: 1.4};
  
  Map.addLayer(image.clip(roi), visParams, "Output");
  Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
  
  var imageRGB = image.visualize({bands:['B4','B3','B2'], min:0 , max:0.3, gamma:1.4});
  
  var descrpt = "Seattle_" + image.date().getInfo();
  
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: imageRGB,
    description: descrpt,
    folder: "sidv2",
    scale: 10,
    region: roi,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    shardSize: 1024
    });

  return 1;
  }

var images = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-12-31')
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
  .aside(print)
  .map(exportImageRGB);
```

In the line where I format the description `var descrpt = "Seattle_" + image.date().getInfo();` it's throwing me the error:

```
Line 23: A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations
```

I would assume from the client side I can't just retrieve image attributes like this.

How could I achieve this?